# Google maps выделить часть дороги

Tags: google-maps-api

Хочу установить google maps api на локале но чтобы мог отметить дороги
прим- вставил 2 маркера и хочу что это часть дороги перекрасить в крассный цвет(или другие )
и сохранить ети изменение

зарание спосибо

Answer (score 1):

гугль мапс не работает локально, только вживую.

другое дело, если вы на основе картографии гугль будете отмечать какие-то свои конструкции, - тогда да, полученные результаты можно парсить в массивы координат, которые можно накапливать в базе для последующего использования на карте.